# Using JSDoc with namespaces and a variant form of function definition

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I've been trying to use JsDoc for documenting my javascript but I keep coming across this hurdle. It keeps saying "nothing to document, exiting"

Here is the peice of code I'm trying to document:

```
/**
 * Container for all editing methods
 * @namespace
 */
var FREdit = {

    /**
     * Toggle value for editing
     * @type Number
     */
    isToggleOn:0,

    /**
     * Initialize editing 
     */
    init: function(){
        this.initPopups();
    },

    /**
     * Function to enable editing 
     */
    enable: function(){
        this.enableTitles();
            this.isToggleOn = 1;
    }
};
```

Above I'm using namespace. Even if I use a variant form of function definition in JavaScript, JSDoc doesn't seem to recognise it. Eg:

```
/**
 * Just any function
 */
var any_function = function(){

};
```

Any idea how to get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question I'm guessing you're using JSDoc.
The original JSDoc has been unsupported for a while now.

I suggest you use [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) as it has much better support.
According to their documentation you can [document the class pattern](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/CookBook).
Take a look at their examples and you should be good to go!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I found jsdoc-toolkit after posting this and it works perfectly fine!